# how to fix dynamic textview in android studio?

Tags: textview

[image]

I am trying to resolve this problem it shows an error every time.so how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Has to be `android:text` and not `tool:text`

Also, follow the convention of using camel case for resource directories. That is, `@string` instead of `@String`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do exactly, but I think you just want to set the `text` attribute. `text` is in the `android` namespace, so you have to use it.

Also, the resource name is `@string`, and not `@String`, which might cause errors later.

Comment: I applied all type of thing but it show attribute error